# How to properly export classes from NodeJS file?

Tags: node.js, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to export my classes in following file. I tried this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

class Client extends Discord.Client {}
class PermissionNode {}
class PermissionNodesManager {}

module.exports.Client = Client;
module.exports.PermissionNode = PermissionNode;
module.exports.PermissionNodesManager = PermissionNodesManager;
```

This does not throw any errors but Visual Studio Code's IntelliSense autocomplete is not working. In type it says `any`.
I just simply want to require this file like this:

```js
const Classes = require('those/exported/classes.js');
```

and use it like this:

```js
let another_client = new Classes.Client();
```

or like this:

```js
const MB = require('classes.js');

/**
 * @param {MB.Client} client
 * @param {MB.PermissionNode} node
 * @param {MB.PermissionNodesManager} manager
 */
let func = (client, node, manager) => {}
```

Both ways don't work. IntelliSense is showing something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR0TU.jpg

How do I export those classes for IntelliSense to work?

Comment: If your primary issue is that your IDE's autocomplete isn't working, it'd be tough for us to say exactly why that is without you telling us in your question which IDE it is you're using.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick workaround (not recommended) is the following (a "named"?/destructured require).

I have no idea why this works and OP's way doesn't.

```js
const { Client } = require('./module.js');

/**
 * @type {Client}
 */
let x;
x. // intellisense (correct): addListener, channels, ...
```

Just a side note, the following doesn't work.

```js
const M1 = require('./module.js');
const { Client } = M1;

/**
 * @type {Client}
 */
let x;
x. // intellisense (wrong): apply, arguments, bind, ...
```

I don't know what's going on internally in VSCode and/or TypeScript that would cause this behavior -- my understanding is that these code snippets are equivalent.

Comment: this sadly does not solve my issue. I use all my classes in most files

Comment: This suggests it might be an issue with vs code. Have you considered opening an issue with them? @PoProstuMieciek

Comment: I saw some closed issues related to this but they are not really solved. It is very old, because last issues were from 2016. I'm just using your solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add JSDoc-style comment blocks to give VSCode the hint:

```
/**
 * @returns {Client}
 */
module.exports.Client = Client;
/**
 * @returns {PermissionNode}
 */
module.exports.PermissionNode = PermissionNode;
/**
 * @returns {PermissionNodesManager}
 */
module.exports.PermissionNodesManager = PermissionNodesManager;
```

After adding these, IntelliSense properly displays the type:

[image: Script]

Comment: ok this works but if I do something like this:
```js
const MB = require('classes.js');

/**
 * @param {MB.Client} client
 * @param {MB.PermissionNode} node
 * @param {MB.PermissionNodesManager} manager
 */
let func = (client, node, manager) => {}
```

It still does not work. It shows something like this: https://imgur.com/a/McW0Xv8

Comment: do I need to create a module, like discord.js or what?

Comment: @PoProstuMieciek It's impossible to read code in comments and effectively parse it. Please edit your question to include this new information so that it can be effectively read by myself as well as other members of the community.

Comment: sorry, now it is in the question

Comment: @PoProstuMieciek Not reproducible on my end. I'm getting the proper IntelliSense for each as you've declared them in your JSDoc comment, see [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/2YkhYj6.png)

Comment: try to create properties inside class definition. inside that function try to access, for example: `client.name`